# passing a variable with href in html

Tags: php, html

I want to pass a variable along with the link on a button click, while using href. can anyone tell me the exact syntax or if it is even possible?
i want to do something like this: href="link+variable"
so that i can extract the variable and use it on the "link" which will open.

Comment: All of the answers here work. But you may also want to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php with them.

Comment: thank you @katsh and everyone else I have achieved my desired output :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible by doing the following

**site 1**

```
<input type="button" onClick="window.location='http://example.com?var=<?php echo $var ?>'">
```

On the recieving site use the following:

**site 2**

```
<?php
    $var = $_GET['var'];
?>
```

The variable you sent is store in $var in site 2

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean passing a value as a parameter?

`<a href="page.php?value_key=some_value">Link</a>`

Then in PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['value_key'])){
  $var = $_GET['value_key']; //some_value
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is a query string.

A query string uses name value pairs.  The `?` is used to start a query string.  An `&` would be used to string multiple variables together.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?var=value&var2=value2">Pass the variable</a>
```

These variables would be accessible in php by using either `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

On the target php page:

```
$var = $_GET['var'];

$var2 = $_GET['var2'];
```

Comment: and then how will i be accessing the var in www.example.com?

Comment: Well, in your index.php, you would have $var and $var2 variables, and you can do whatever you want from it. Although, you would need to know if you need to use GET[$var] or POST.

Answer (score 0):

Full description how to handle with external variables is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php